# How to build an array that will be updated across many methods

Tags: php

I have to check if an element id is duplicate and if so update it with a "-1".

```
//get all elements and loop through each element
public function main(){
    $products = $this->getProducts();
    foreach($products as $product){
        $formatted_products = $this->processProducts($product);
    }
}
public function processProducts($product){

    //builds a csv with product data
    'id' => $this->duplicateSkus($product->getSku());

    if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
        $csv = $this->getVariants($csv, $product);
    }
}

public function getVariants($csv, $product){
    'id' => $this->duplicateSkus($childProduct->getSku())
}

//my main method where I check if ids are unique
public function duplicateSkus($product_sku){
    if(in_array($product_sku, $products_sku)){
        $product_sku = $product_sku."-1";
    }
    $products_sku[] = $product_sku;
    return $product_sku;

}
```

My issue is with building an array `$products_sku` with all ids and check each one against it.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, much going on in that class, but this is the only part relevant

Comment: Righto, cheers, I'll take a look see :)

Comment: If you wan to check by ids then use array_key_exists instead of in_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array that can be used across the class, make a property for that as such:

```
private $array = array(); // Set up an array for this class only
```

Then you can initialise it:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->array = $this->AssignData; // Initialise the array of data
}

/**
* Assigner for the private $this->array
*/
private function AssignData()
{
    $this->array = ["one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5, "six"=>6, "seven"=>7, "eight"=>8];
}
```

Then you can use it in your class:

```
public function PrintArray()
{
    if (array_key_exists("four", $this->array))
    {
        print $this->array["four"];
    }
}
```

In totality:

```
class Foo
{
    private $array = array(); // Set up an array for this class only

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->array = $this->AsignData; // Initialise the array of data
    }

    /**
    * Assigner for the private $this->array
    */
    private function AsignData()
    {
        $this->array = ["one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5, "six"=>6, "seven"=>7, "eight"=>8];
    }

    public function PrintArray()
    {
        if (array_key_exists("four", $this->array)) //Check the array key exists
        {
            print $this->array["four"];
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Added check function for `array_key_exists`

```
public function CheckKeyExists($key, $search)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $search))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```